# Using the :hover in CSS for links

Tags: css, hover

So I wrote this piece of code to get the hover effect but didn't get it quite right.

```
a:hover{
  background-color: #306203;
}
```

To get the links highlited when I hover on them, but I get the space highlited too. How can I get just the words?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: its a design (architecture) issue. Either move the text into a span and highlight the span or stop giving the anchor a fixed width and create the space with a gap.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```css
a:hover > span {
  background-color: #306203;
}
```

```html
  <a><span>Features</span></a>
```